# Different number of columns each row in a table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, tabular

I would like to make a table with different numbers of cols with PHP and with data from mysql.

To make this possible I think an easy way out is to first print a table with rows and within them rows make a new table with random number of columns. I know this is not a recommended thing to do but I need it this way.

When I do it all the cells got the same value.

Can anyone please help me out?

Example:

[image]

Comment: Are the tags `PHP`,`MYSQL`,`DYNAMIC` relevant to your question at all? Aren't you asking something related to **HTML** tables?

Comment: Using a table is a must? Can't you use div's?

Comment: Use plain `div`'s, float them and give them proper width, done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try code as given below

```
<?php
  $rows = array();
  $rows[0][0] = 'A';
  $rows[0][1] = 'B';
  $rows[0][2] = 'C';
  $rows[1][0] = 'D';
  $rows[1][1] = 'f';
  $rows[2][0] = 'f';
  $rows[2][1] = 'k';
  $rows[2][2] = 'f';
  $rows[2][3] = 'j';
  $rows[3][0] = 'j';
  $total_rows = count($rows);

   echo "<table border='2'>";

    for($i = 0;$i < $total_rows; $i++){
    echo "<tr>";
      foreach($rows[$i] AS $col){
        echo "<td>";
            echo $col;
       echo "</td>";
      }
    echo  "</tr>";
   }
echo "</table>";
```

Here `first index of array is showing row number and second index showing column number of table`.

thanks

Comment: Thanks you for your time! This work exactly what I wished for, with some little modification to fit my existing code!

Comment: this is still an invalid html hack since number of `TD` in rows will be different and no use of `colspan`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you want is tables. This can be accomplished using divs, and floating the child divs left:

Html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">
   ....
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
   ....
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
   ....
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">
   ....
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
   ....
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
   ....
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
   ....
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
   ....
  </div>
  as much divs ...
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.clear {
   clear:both;
}
.cell {
   width:100px;
   float:left;
}
```

Comment: Why not `.row {clear: both;}`? IMO, `.clear` is unclean and unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Using one row tables and placing them in one box with div, might be another way to do it. Something like this:

```
<?php
// Array example
 $row = array('data1'  => '1',
              'data2'  => '2',
              'data3'  => '3',
              'data4'  => '4',
              'data5'  => '5',
              'data6'  => '6',
              'data7'  => '7',
              'data8'  => '8',
              'data9'  => '9',
              'data10' => '10');
?>

<style type="text/css">
  /*<![CDATA[*/
 .TablesBox {
  border: solid 2px #000000;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
 }

 .Tables tr, .Tables td {
  width: auto;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 1px;
 }

 .Tables td {
  border: solid 1px #000000;
  margin: 0;
 }

  /*]]>*/
</style>

<div class="TablesBox">
 <!--5 columns row-->
 <table class="Tables">
  <tr>
   <td><?php echo $row['data1']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['data2']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['data3']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['data4']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['data5']; ?></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <!--2 columns row-->
 <table class="Tables">
  <tr>
   <td><?php echo $row['data6']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['data7']; ?></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <!--3 columns row-->
 <table class="Tables">
  <tr>
   <td><?php echo $row['data8']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['data9']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['data10']; ?></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 ...
</div>
```